# MAMP Pro 3.0.6 crashes with every save

Tags: php, macos, mamp, mamp-pro

[MAMP Pro](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/) closes unexpectedly *every* time I click the Save button.

It appears that my settings are saved, and applied after re-launching the application.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch MAMP Pro
2. Enter OSX authentication to allow services to start
3. Click Hosts tab
4. Add a new host or edit an existing host
5. Edit a setting
6. Click Save
7. MAMP Pro closes unexpectedly, prompting to file a report with Apple
8. Restart MAMP Pro. The settings are saved, so hit Stop/Start to restart services.

The [crash report](http://f.cl.ly/items/2M0Q2l2K1c0z2v2I1o0T/MAMP%20PRO_2014-09-09-105914_localhost.crash.txt) says:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
```

I have four virtual hosts defined, each with the IP address set to "*" (the default). They are using the port 80/443/3306 configuration.

Wondering if this was a network issue, I tried restarting my machine, but that didn't seem to fix the problem.

I am using the trial version of MAMP Pro on Mac OSX 10.9.4 ([more specs](http://cl.ly/image/43422p0R2w21)). If it didn't crash every time I saved, I would almost certainly buy it.

I also have a bug filed at http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=4595.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling MAMP?

Comment: I ran the MAMP Pro uninstaller, deleted all application files, re-downloaded, and reinstalled. Your idea is a sound one, but unfortunately the problem with saving and crashing persists.

Comment: I've also experienced this with a brand-new install with a single host with default settings. Crash every time I save any setting. FWIW.